# How to convert .mdf/.mds to .iso?

Tags: video, file-conversion

I have an old [Alcohol 120%](http://www.alcohol-soft.com/) CD/DVD image file that I'd like to convert to an .iso image. I have tried simply renaming the file thus (disregarding the 4 KB .mds file):

video.mdf --> video.iso.

This *sort of* worked. Most of the video played perfectly (in VLC) but then the final three minutes were silent with a blank screen.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you consider reinstalling Alcohol (on a PC or virtual machine) and converting the image into .iso?

Comment: Yes, but the image is so old that I don't want to go to the trouble of installing Windows just to access it. I can do this on the command line on my Xubuntu box but I wonder if there's a way on the Mac. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How do you do it under Linux then?

Comment: Using the mdf2iso tool @Eir mentions. :) It's late here now but I'll give this a go in the morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use very simple command line program mdf2iso for this.
it is available via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) (for example).

**PS:** This utility can be also used in any Linux, *BSD and Windows systems

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try in the morning and report back. I may try and find the source and compile it altho' I'll probably only ever use it the one time. Cheers.

Comment: How is your experience with it?

Comment: Really sorry, I totally forgot about this. Worked a treat. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is able to read quite a lot of video formats. It shares a bunch of libraries with VLC anyway so you may be able to convert your files as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you only need to mount the image, is to use [DAMON Tools for Mac](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtMacLite). Not free but if the trial expires it can be uninstalled/reinstalled using AppCleaner.